# React self increment timer

Tags: reactjs, setinterval

I wanted to start a timer when the page loads, and my code is like following:

```
  function App() {
     const [sec, setSec] = useState(0);

     useEffect(()=>{
      setInterval(()=>{setSec(prev=>prev+1)
      }, 1000)}, [sec])

  return (
    <span>{sec}</span>
  )}
```

But the counter increments not just every second but very fast. I didnt know what the issue is.

I think the `setInterval()` will run every second, which updates the `sec` variable, which in turn would calls the callback function in `useEffect()` so it can run again.

I did find some example code for setting a react timer online but they use `useRef()` to hold a `setInterval()` callback function and then update the `sec` variable like `setSec(sec+1)`. I loosely understand the logic but not completely, and I can't figure out why my code does not work.

Thank you so much if anyone can help me. Sorry if it is some simple thing that I missed.

Comment: Remove the `sec` from your dependency array `[sec]` --> `[]`

Comment: when i removed it, the counter still runs way faster than expected.

Comment: You probably also want to assign your interval to a variable (`intervalId`) and then clear it in the useEffect's cleanup function `return () => {clearInterval(intervalId)}`. It might be running faster than expected due to `React.StrictMode` which would create two intervals (hard to say without seeing the rest of your code though).

Comment: Read this article: https://overreacted.io/making-setinterval-declarative-with-react-hooks/. This a good article to understand and implement intervals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two problems.

First, remove `sec` from the dependency array on `useEffect`.  You should use an interval ***or*** an effect dependency, but not both.  When you use both you're essentially creating a new interval on every re-render, so every re-render will increase the amount of increments and the rate will compound indefinitely.

If you want to rely on the dependency array and the effect re-running on every render, you'd just use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`.  For example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    setSec((prev) => prev + 1);
  }, 1000);
}, [sec]);
```

That way each re-render of the component (and each re-invoking of the effect) only performs one increment, not a new ongoing interval of incremenets.

---

Second, and more subtly, the effect is leaving a side-effect that isn't cleaned up.  This will be evident in a development environment if the component technically renders twice, and you'd see your counter increment by 2 instead of 1 every second.

You can "clean up" an effect by returning a cleanup function from the `useEffect` callback.  React would use that function when the component unloads.  For example:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const x = setInterval(() => {
    setSec((prev) => prev + 1);
  }, 1000);

  // return a cleanup function here
  return () => clearInterval(x);
}, []);
```